# Regex .net Only getting last match from line item list

Tags: .net, regex, nsregularexpression

I don't use Regex much. I am trying to get part numbers from a string. I spent a day so far.

I am expecting 2 matches for "Line"

```
 __40X0343 1.00
 __C734X77G 2.00
```

and within those matches I expect these matches

```
PartNo 40X0343 OrderQuantity 1.00 for Line 1
PartNo C734X77G OrderQuantity 2.00 for Line 2
```

but I only get the last match not both.  Any help would be great

regex:

```
(?x)Required\sDate
(?<Line>__
(?<PartNo>[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\S
(?<OrderQuantity>[0-9.]+)
)*
```

string

```
__Required Date__40X0343 1.00__C734X77G 2.00__Net Order:__Sales Tax:__Freight:__Order Total:__0.00 __0.00 __5,328.50 __5,328.50 __or by fax
```

results from a regex tool

```
Full match 2-44 `Required Date__40X0343 1.00__C734X77G 2.00` 
Group `Line` 29-44 `__C734X77G 2.00` 
Group `PartNo` 31-39 `C734X77G` 
Group `OrderQuantity` 40-44 `2.00`
```

Edited to better illustrate my problem

Comment: can you edit to make clearer and show input and expected output.

Comment: Try this: (?<=Required\sDate.*?)(?<Line>__(?<PartNo>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\s(?<OrderQuantity>[0-9.]+))+?. You will get 2 matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your regex `(?<PartNo>[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\S` captures a group named `PartNo` and matches `[a-zA-Z0-9-]*` followed by `\S` which match not a whitespace character but in according to your example data that should be `\s` which matches a whitespace charcter

You get only the last match because you are [repeating the capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

If you expect 2 matches you can capture the `OrderQuantity` in the same group as `PartNo`.

Using C# you could use [Group.Captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=netframework-4.7.2) and use the group name `PartNo`. Then you can get the captures and loop them.

For example:

```
string pattern = @"(?x)Required\sDate
(?<Line>__
(?<PartNo>[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\s[0-9.]+)
)*";
string str = @"__Required Date__40X0343 1.00__C734X77G 2.00__Net Order:__Sales Tax:__Freight:__Order Total:__0.00 __0.00 __5,328.50 __5,328.50 __or by fax";        
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matchColl = regex.Matches(str);
if (matchColl != null) 
    foreach (Match match in matchColl) 
        foreach (Capture c in match.Groups["PartNo"].Captures) 
            Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
```

Result

```
40X0343 1.00
C734X77G 2.00
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/VyXvOj)

Another option is to have multiple named capturing groups with `PartNo` and `OrderQuantity` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o730bt/1/) or without the `OrderQuantity` group [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o730bt/2)

Comment: why don't I get 2 Matches?

Comment: when I add another line item it did not work. test string->  __Required Date__40X0343 1.00__C734X7G 3.00__C734X77G 2.00__Net Order:__Sales Tax:__Freight:__Order Total:__0.00 __0.00 __5,328.50 __5,328.50 __or by fax

Comment: @XGSDEV That is because now you have 3 groups you want to capture. If you use the C# code with Group.Captures it will work https://ideone.com/ycKEYG or do you use another language live VB.NET?

Comment: c#. I'm trying to get matches for "Line" (not captures)  so "PartNo" and "OrderQuantity" are available per line. I have had something like this working in the past (match on "Line") after much trial and error

Comment: @XGSDEV To get your multiple matches, did you try  using an infinite lookbehind as suggested in the comments? You can go to  http://regexstorm.net/tester and use this as the regex `(?x)(?<=^__Required\sDate.*?)
(?<Line>__
(?<PartNo>[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\s
(?<OrderQuantity>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
)*`

Comment: regex 101 says "* A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width
? The preceding token is not quantifiable".

Comment: @XGSDEV That is because .NET uses a different regex engine which supports lookbehind with an infinite quantifier and that engine is not present on regex101. That is why you have to test it on regexstorm.net/tester instead which has the right engine.

Comment: still only1 match. I have an example that works with multiple matches (different data and different patter) just unsuccessful at reverse engineering so far

Comment: @XGSDEV My bad, I forgot something. This should give you 2 matches with the groupnames `(?x)(?<=^__Required\sDate.*?)(?<Line>__ (?<PartNo>[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\s(?<OrderQuantity>\d+(?:\.\d+)?))+?` You can see them when you click on the tab `Table`

Answer (score 0):

As first steps, it looks like you're omitting repetition syntax, and as a byproduct, making it harder to get capturing groups afterward.  In other words, this part:

```
    (?<PartNo>[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)__
```

Should look something more like this:

```
    ((?<PartNo>[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)__)+
```

The `+` means you expect to find 1 or more of them, the __ are included in the outer capturing group because you need them to extend all the way to the last part number, and the non-__ chars are in their own, inner capturing group so you can just extract those.

If you're sure there will always be a part number, I'd drop the `?` in the inner capturing group, technically it contradicts the `+` and though that doesn't seem to matter when I tried it (in Notepad++), no point in confusing the issue.

It seems like you'll need to do some careful post-capture evaluation of capturing-group identities, though I don't use aliases like `<PartNo>` and so I can't say for sure, maybe it's not so hard.

Comment: I was under the impression that the ? was part of the  syntax for a Named Capture Group

Comment: You may be right, I don't use named captures, but it looks like my answer was tossed anyway.  Eventually I'll look closer at that syntax.